# GCE instance - OPENVPN - not resolving any address

Tags: google-compute-engine, vpn, openvpn

I don't have internet access when i'm connected to my vpn server.
I have tried manually to install debian on my home virtual machine and runs without problem, so is not the vpn server problem.
I want GCE debian instance to get connect to openvpn and have internet access from that ip address
Let me know what i'm missing?

here is my .ovpn config

```
remote xxxxxxx 7777 tcp

verb 4
client
nobind
dev tun
cipher AES-128-CBC
key-direction 1
redirect-gateway def1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
# uncomment below lines for use with linux
script-security 2
# if you use resolved
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# if you use systemd-resolved first install openvpn-systemd-resolved package
#up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
#down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved

<cert>
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            e2:7e:b0:e5:dd:37:33:6c:36:49:76:2f:ec:0e:73:e7
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ca
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 18 14:27:52 2021 GMT
            Not After : Feb 21 14:27:52 2024 GMT
        Subject: CN=gitlab
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d3:51:b2:....
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                1B:56:09:AE:B4:5D:26:18:....
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:92:76:43:....
                DirName:/CN=ca
                serial:02:D6:....

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         52:32:ca:......
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
cert here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
key here
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
cert here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
key here
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

It's get connected to vpn successfully and nothing happens no access of the internet...
UPDATE :
I have edit and enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Server config file :

```
# server 172.16.100.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
tls-server
ca /etc/openvpn/easyrsa/pki/ca.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easyrsa/pki/private/server.key
cert /etc/openvpn/easyrsa/pki/issued/server.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/easyrsa/pki/dh.pem
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/easyrsa/pki/crl.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easyrsa/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
cipher AES-128-CBC
#management 127.0.0.1 8989
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
topology subnet
#proto tcp
#port 1194
#dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log
user nobody
group nogroup
push "topology subnet"
push "route-metric 9999"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
```

Comment: Can you please share your server config?

Comment: Updated the first post @2ps Please check

Comment: Anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

I would try making this modification to push everything from the server.  Topology is usually set on the server side, and not on the client side.  And you want to push the redirect gateway from the server, not from the client.  I added back the server subnet so that we knew the source ip addresses for masquerade / nat.

```
# push "topology subnet"
# push "route-metric 9999"
server 172.16.100.0 255.255.255.0
topology subnet
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
```

Lastly, you'll want to make sure you have masquerade turned on in iptables so that your traffic is natted on the way out of your openvpn server.  [Here is a link describing the process](https://arashmilani.com/post?id=53).

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.100.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

You may have a different ethernet interface name, but you can find the correct name using `ifconfig`.